# text box to not accept decimal values only for JPY currency

Tags: angularjs

I have done a text box validation for amount which should accept only numbers or decimal numbers.Its working fine but the problem is i do not want this validation to happen in case of JPY currency as in the text box should not accept decimal values.I wonder how to achieve this for one currency.
I have used custom directive for the input field validation.Please have a look.

Please help.

```js
.directive('allowOnlyDigits', function () {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if(!ngModelCtrl) {
        return; 
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            var val = '';
        }
        var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
        var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');

        if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
            decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
            clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
        }

        if (val !== clean) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return clean;
      });

      element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute to check currency.

```
.directive('allowOnlyDigits', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$validators.onlyDigits = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;

                if (attrs['currency'] !== 'JPY') {
                    return /^\d*(?:\.\d{2}){0,1}$/.test(value);
                } else {
                   return /^\d*$/.test(value); 
                }
            };

            element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In HTML:

```
<input type ='text' ng-model='model' currency='JPY' allow-only-digits>
```

Comment: Can u tell me the else part for JPY that is the text box validation to accept only numbers.I know the validation to accept only numbers using pattern so do not know how to put it here.

Comment: For validation, you should use `$validators` instead of `$parsers`. You can use this `/^\d*$/.test(value)` to check if value is only numbers. Updated answer as well.

Comment: after decimal only two digits are allowed in case of other currencies.Now with the recent code its not happening

Comment: Just change `/^\d*(?:\.\d+){0,1}$/` to `/^\d*(?:\.\d{2}){0,1}$/`

Comment: Not working.Also validation is not happening.Its accepting alphabets too now.

Comment: The code above only validates whether the value is digit only. It doesn't block user from entering alphabets.